# I want to start Rocket in a module out of `main()` but failed

Tags: rust, rust-rocket

I want to start Rocket in a module out of `main()`, thus can simplify `main()` but I failed. I modified the [Quicktart](https://rocket.rs/guide/getting-started/) from rocket

The code:

```
mod myRocket {
    #![feature(plugin)]
    #![plugin(rocket_codegen)]
    extern crate rocket;

    #[get("/")]
    fn index() -> &'static str {
        "Hello, world!"
    }

    pub fn startup() {
        rocket::ignite().mount("/", routes![index]).launch();
    }
}


fn main() {
    myRocket::startup();
}
```

The error:

```
error: cannot find macro `routes!` in this scope
--> src\main.rs:12:37
|
12 |         rocket::ignite().mount("/", routes![index]).launch();
|
```

I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: IIRC, the plugin declaration must be in the main

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I achieved. My project's crate is `rocket_demo`

main.rs

```
extern crate rocket_demo; 

use rocket_demo::my_rocket;

fn main() {
    my_rocket::startup();
}
```

lib.rs

```
#![feature(plugin)]
#![plugin(rocket_codegen)]
extern crate rocket;

pub mod my_rocket;
```

The first three lines can't be in my_rocket/mod.rs, otherwise `routes!` will not find!

my_rocket/mod.rs

```
#[get("/")]
fn index() -> &'static str {
    "Hello, world!"
}

pub fn startup() {
    ::rocket::ignite().mount("/", routes![index]).launch();
}
```